# Why is 'et al' appearing in markdown bibliography?

Tags: r, knitr, pandoc, pander

I'm trying to make a bibliography in markdown. To build the bibliography, I'm using the knitr package and pandoc in R to convert a .Rmd file to a PDF.

The entries in my .bib file look like these, taken from http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/demo/biblio.bib:

```
@Book{item1,
author="John Doe",
title="First Book",
year="2005",
address="Cambridge",
publisher="Cambridge University Press"
}

@Article{item2,
author="John Doe",
title="Article",
year="2006",
journal="Journal of Generic Studies",
volume="6",
pages="33-34"
}
```

To build my bibliography, I'm using the following function, taken from: http://quantifyingmemory.blogspot.co.il/2013/02/reproducible-research-with-r-knitr.html

```
knitsPDF <- function(name) {
  library(knitr)
  knit(paste0(name, ".Rmd"), encoding = "utf-8")
  system(paste0("pandoc -o ", name, ".pdf ", name, ".md --bibliography /Users/.../Desktop/test.bib --csl /Users/.../Desktop/taylor-and-francis-harvard-x.csl"))
}
```

The contents of my .Rmd file is

```
This is some text [@item1]

This is more text [@item2]

References
```

And the contents of the output PDF is:

```
This is some text (Doe 2005)
This is more text (Doe 2006)

Bibliography
Doe, J. et al., 2005. First Book. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press. 

Doe, J. et al., 2006. Article. Journal of Generic Studies, 6, 33–34.
```

Note the 'et al' appearing in bibliography. Why is et al appearing and how can I stop it appearing? I need bibliography to be:

```
Bibliography
    Doe, J., 2005. First Book. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press. 

    Doe, J., 2006. Article. Journal of Generic Studies, 6, 33–34.
```

Comment: I'm not that experienced with pandoc but have you tried a different style? I would guess this is a problem in the style you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed this was just a problem with the style file. Downloading this style file: http://www.zotero.org/styles/harvard-durham-university-business-school

and changing this code

```
knitsPDF <- function(name) {
  library(knitr)
  knit(paste0(name, ".Rmd"), encoding = "utf-8")
  system(paste0("pandoc -o ", name, ".pdf ", name, ".md --bibliography /Users/.../Desktop/test.bib --csl /Users/.../Desktop/harvard-durham-university-business-school.csl"))
}
```

solved the problem

Comment: Since the default style you use never is correct, I would consider it a bug and submit it to the author.

Comment: I think this is a bug in citeproc-hs, the CSL processor of pandoc. The only noticeable difference between https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles/blob/master/taylor-and-francis-harvard-x.csl and https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles/blob/master/harvard-durham-university-business-school.csl is that the former style applies italics to the "et al." in the bibliography. citeproc-hs bugs can be reported at https://code.google.com/p/citeproc-hs/issues/list